# Как выполнить команду "если(if)" на result1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом "если(if)" не могу выполнить проверку на result1, а так без него код работает нормально.

[image: запуск кода]

'''

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from gui import Ui_Rocoon
import os

# Создать приложение
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Создать форму и инициализировать пользовательский интерфейс
Rocoon = QtGui.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Rocoon()
ui.setupUi(Rocoon)
Rocoon.show()


# =============================================================
# Hook logik

def network():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.pushButton.text())
ui.pushButton.clicked.connect( network )

def network():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.pushButton_2.text())
ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect( network )

def network():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.pushButton_3.text())
ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect( network )

def network():
    ui.lineEdit.setText(ui.pushButton_4.text())
ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect( network )

"""
def command1():
    result_network = ui.lineEdit.text()
    ui.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Rocoon", '<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#069d9f;\">' + command + '</span></p></body></html>', None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
"""

# --------------------------------------------------------------


#ip4 = "{line_1}'.'{line_2}'.'{line_3}'.'{line_4}"
def network2():

    command = 'netsh interface ip set address name="' + ui.lineEdit.text() + '" static ' + ui.lineEdit_6.text() + '.' + ui.lineEdit_5.text() + '.' + ui.lineEdit_7.text() + '.' + ui.lineEdit_4.text() + ' 255.255.255.0'
    result1 = os.system(command) # на выходе получим 0(получилось) или 1(ошибка)

    if result1 == "0":
        ui.label_2.connect.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Rocoon", '<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#069d9f;\">Ip4 изменился</span></p></body></html>', None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
    elif result1 == "1":
        ui.label_2.connect.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Rocoon", '<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#ac1733;\">Ошибка в вводе данных</span></p></body></html>', None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect( network2 )


# --------------------------------------------------------------



# Запустить основной цикл
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

'''

[image: 123]

С этим кодом всё нормально:

```py
if result1 == "0"'
```

А вот с этим кодом проблемы он пишет "синтактическая ошибка" :

```py
ui.label_2.connect.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Rocoon", '<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#ac1733;\">Ошибка в вводе данных</span></p></body></html>', None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))'''
```

Comment: system возращает тип данных int

Comment: Raccoon 1. Есть большие сомнения в правильном написании строки `if result1 == "0"`, попробуйте написать `if result1 == 0`. 2. Строку `ui.label_2.connect.setText(...)`, попробуйте написать так `ui.label_2.setText(...)`

Comment: S.Nick Спасибо большое это помогло
я написал таким образом 
```if result1 == int("0"):
  ui.label_2.setText(. . .)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите какой тип данных у вас в result1. Для этого ниже выведите тип.

```py
print(result1, type(result1))
```

Исходя из полученного результата приводите result1 к int или str или добавьте дополнительную проверку:

```py
elif result1 == "1" or result1 == 1:
```

Comment: С этим кодом:

```python if result1 == "0"' ```
всё нормально.
А вот с этим кодом проблемы он пишет "синтактическая ошибка" :

```python ui.label_2.connect.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Rocoon", '<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#ac1733;\">Ошибка в вводе данных</span></p></body></html>', None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)) ```

Comment: Добавь, пожалуйста, скрин ошибки в описание

Comment: Вот скрин:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7yiG.png